# Hostname aliases in LDAP and phpLDAPadmin

Tags: hosts-file, ldap

What is the best method of storing multiple hostname aliases in LDAP? Currently, the hosts file I wish to migrate has many entries such as

```
172.24.3.54    workstation114.example.net wks114 exphost3
```

From my testing, using `device` and `ipHost` classes works fine, using the `ipHostNumber` attribute and multiple `cn` attributes for the different hostnames. However, using the canonical hostname's cn for the rdn then causes problems with phpLDAPadmin, which refuses to let you edit the aliases later.

Is there a better way of implementing this setup, or is this something I'll need to hack around in phpLDAPadmin to fix?

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a problem with phpLDAPadmin, and there is nothing wrong with having multiple `cn` attributes - we switched to Apache Directory Studio instead which has no problems in maintaining this structure.